# Node.js - Discord.js v14 - fetching a channel returns undefined / does not work

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Attempting to define `channel` with this code will return undefined.

```
const { Events, InteractionType, Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    ],
  })

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {

        if(interaction.type == InteractionType.ApplicationCommand){
            const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if (!command) {
                console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
                return;
            }
    
            try {
                await command.execute(interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
        else if(interaction.isAutocomplete()){
            const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if(!command) {
                console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
                return;
            }

            try{
                await command.autocomplete(interaction);
            } catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
         else if(interaction.isButton()){
            console.log(client.channels);
            const channel = await client.channels.fetch('1074044721535656016 ');
            console.log(client.channels);
            console.log(channel);
        }
    },
};
```

`const channel = await client.channels.fetch('1074044721535656016 ');` Is the main line here.
At the bottom and top of the code is where the important stuff for this question is. I believe I am not properly using the fetch method.

As evidenced by `console.log(client.channels);` I'm trying to look at the channels cache, but for some reason the channel isn't there, hence I'm using `fetch()` instead of `cache.get()`.

Thank you for the help!

Other info:
Running npm list shows:
discord.js@14.7.1, dotenv@16.0.3
Node.js v19.6.0

[How I got my channel id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WOl7.png)

Error Message:

```
ChannelManager {} //<--- this is from the first console.log
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present
```

Is the problem because the channel is undefined or because it hasn't resolved yet?

Comment: The implementation is correct, but how are you getting your channel id?

Comment: I am getting it by right clicking the channel with developer mode on and clicking copy Id. I added an image to my original post.

Comment: I meant try with `await client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID")`

Comment: `.fetch()` already checks the cache before making an API call, also `.get()` is not asynchronous and does not require the `await` keyword

Comment: client.channels.cache.get('1074044721535656016'); is undefined and it is still undefined with await.

Answer (score 0):

Check your channel ID it may be formatted like:

guild id / channel id

Comment: The guild ID and channel ID do not overlap.

Comment: can you send what you copied?

Comment: 1074044721535656016 is the channel id

Answer (score 0):

Use `interaction.client` instead of making a new client object. The interaction already has its own client object with the related properties.